# Android function to accept Strings and String resources

Tags: android

I have the following interface/contract in my application

```
interface View {

    void showError(@StringRes int message);

    void showError(String message);

    void showLoading();

    void dismissLoading();

    void accountCreated();
}
```

I have 2 `showError` functions, one is accepting any String as a parameter and the other is accepting Android String resources (int).

Is there a way to use just one more generic `showError` to accept both parameters?

Comment: use 1 showError and change String/int to Object and when you get the callback check the instance of the Object and perform task accordingly

Comment: You have correctly overloaded `showError` method. What exactly do you mean by more generic way of doing it?

Comment: @user3161880 The goal is whenever i implement this interface, i will not need to override 2 functions that do the exact same thing. which is show a toast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
void showError(Object message){
   if(message instanceof String){

   }else if(message instanceof Integer){

   }
}
```

Comment: String resource is an int, is int an instance of Interger?

Comment: @TareKhoury `instanceof int` isn't possible. `int` will be auto-boxed to an `Integer`